# Jquery and Ajax script for updating data without opening the new page

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i update the email and press enter the update page is opening , is there any jquery or ajax script for submitting details to update.php with our opening it

```
<form id="myForm" action="update.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();"method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Enter your email here"    />
<br><center><input class="button" type="image" src="rss.png" /></center>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this jQuery plugin:

[jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/): it allows you to easily and unobtrusively upgrade HTML forms to use AJAX.

As example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: when i place a mouse on input form, i am getting the alert .

Comment: it works thanks . i'm used 1.4 verson of jquery ,so it not works previous

Comment: You are wellcome, if it's worked it accept the answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're asking how to do an ajax request, but if you wire up the submit event for your form and call preventDefault() on the event passed in to the handler you're using, it will prevent the browser from navigating to the action url:

```
$('#myForm').bind('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do your ajax
});
```

If you're asking how to construct the ajax call, you'll need to clarify that.

Comment: i want to open an popup dialog instead of opening page update.php

Comment: So unless you want to roll your own (dialog box), I'd recommend using a plugin that does it for you (jquery ui, kendoui, etc.) and load the return data/html from your ajax call into the div/container that you're using for the popup dialog.